# MalformedResponse at expected_inputs[0]: Responses must provide at least one possible intent if this is not the final response. What does it mean?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I created a very simple agent on dialogflow. Every now and then, even using static responses (where only the session ID changes), the application crashes  (both on Google Assistant and in the simulator).

On the logs I find the message in question: "MalformedResponse at expected_inputs [0]: Responses must provide at least one possible if this is not the final response. What does it mean?".
I don't understand what it means.
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. That i've noted is that this problem doesn't ocurre every time. The behavior is really unstable.

I'm using 2 required parameters in the intent. I don't know if that has something to do with the problem.

MalformedResponse at expected_inputs[0].input_prompt: 'input_prompt' is empty 
MalformedResponse at expected_inputs[0]: Responses must provide at least one possible intent if this is not the final response

Comment: Yes, it's my same situation. I also have two required parameters in the intent. I have the same mistake. 

And even in my case, it doesn't always do that.
I also add that I started having the problem for about a week. Everything worked properly before.

Comment: Ok, is good to know that. Ive lost a lot of time finding the problem. Something that I've noted is that if you deploy the Mary's bike sample with the same kind of code (2 required parameters) it doesn't fail
It uses sys.time and sys.date params
I don't know if this has something to do.

Im in contact with the Google support.
If you want you can fill the form in this page:
They then send you a mail asking you more information.

https://developers.google.com/actions/support/?authuser=1

Comment: This is the sample that's working fine:https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-bike-shop-nodejs

Comment: I'm having the same error and am also in contact with support. They've been investigating this for a while now. Did either of you get a response that resolved the issue from them yet?

Comment: They answer this yesterday: "Hi Alberto,

This issue has already been escalated to our engineering team. You are correct about required parameters causing the problem. Our engineering team is working thoroughly to resolve this since it is affecting some other AoG projects as well. "

Comment: Thanks for sharing that update Alberto! We're playing the waiting game then.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, appears to be caused when you use own parameters, not when use sys. parameters.
Google answer me the following:

"Hi Alberto,

This issue has already been escalated to our engineering team. You are correct about required parameters causing the problem. Our engineering team is working thoroughly to resolve this since it is affecting some other AoG projects as well. "

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same issue when I was using custom entities as input parameters to my action.

I was asking for 2 custom parameters and one system (sys.color) and triggering the same with input prompts.

I found a workaround for that by taking all 3 in separate intents and using the response of the previous intent as a trigger to enter the next parameter, also by making the training phrases as sample values of the custom parameter.

I am still in contact with Dialogflow Suppport and waiting for bug fix but it works for now.